# Usage of Var Pattern in C# 7

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

I've seen this example of var pattern in the new C# 7

```
if (o is var x) Console.WriteLine($"it's a var pattern with the type {x?.GetType()?.Name}");
```

What is the different of just use:

```
var x = o;
Console.WriteLine($"it's a var pattern with the type {x?.GetType()?.Name}");
```

And when this pattern is an useful solution.

Comment: The difference is one is a conditional `WriteLine`, the other is not.

Comment: I'm trying to think of a useful usage for this pattern (I can't see one) or if its a language glitch. Another possibility is that `var` could actually be a type, although that would be hideous.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I cannot realize why I should use a if statement if the condition is always true.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker No, it's *not* conditional, as the `var` pattern is always true--that's the point of the question.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There's no practical difference in that example. It's unfortunate that so many sites use that—even [the language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#var).

The main reason you would use the `x is var y` pattern if you need a temporary variable within a Boolean expression. For example:

```
allLists.Where(list => list.Count() is var count && count >= min && count <= max)
```

By creating temporary variable `count` we can use it multiple times without the performance cost of calling `Count()` each time.

In that example we could have used `is int count` instead—the `var` is just a stylistic choice. However, there are two cases where `var` is needed: for [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) or if you want to allow nulls. The latter is because `null` doesn't match any type.

Specifically for `if`, though, you *could* do the same thing: `if (list.Count() is var count && count >= min && count <= max)`. But that's clearly silly. The general consensus seems to be that there's no good use for it in `if`. But the language won't prevent you, because banning this particular expression form from that specific expression-taking statement would complicate the language.

Comment: The documentation issue has been [resolved](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/11804).

Answer (score 3):

As the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904000/different-behavior-in-pattern-matching-when-using-var-or-explicit-type) asked by [InBetween](https://stackoverflow.com/users/767890/inbetween), explains one usage of var pattern is when is use switch statements as follows:

```
string s = null;
var collection = new string[] { "abb", "abd", "abc", null};
switch (s)
{
    case "xyz":
        Console.WriteLine("Is xyz");
        break;

    case var ss when (collection).Contains(s):
        Console.WriteLine("Is in list");
        break;

    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Failed!");
        break;

}
```

AS [Aydin Adn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2599907/aydin-adn) said in his answer.