# New C#7 pattern matching and reachability

Tags: c#

This is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45844586/767890) question, which seems to me a language glitch or a missing warning in the compiler. My reasoning is that `is` will always return `true` in expressions of the following type:

```
int i;
if (i is var j) ....
```

Taking it a step further, consider the following code:

```
int i;
if (i is int) .... //Compiler warning: The given expression is always
                   //of the provided ('int') type.
```

But, same as with `var`, if you do:

```
if (i is int j) ...
else ...
```

You won't get any warning (neither given expression is always `true` or unreachable code detected in the `else` clause) to what, essentially, is the same behavior.

This makes me consider if maybe my initial reasoning is wrong. Is there a some obscure use/corner case I'm missing where this really makes a difference? And if not, is the missing warning and the inconsistent behavior an oversight (or even bug) in the compiler?

Comment: Modified the question slightly to show its not an exact duplicate. I'm essentially asking about an inconsistent behavior of the compiler, not simply a use case of this pattern.

Comment: If you realize (or suspect) that your answer to another question is wrong, then rather than duplicating the question to ask the exact same thing a second time, you should correct (or remove) your existing answer, rather than leaving it (even though you don't think it's correct) and posting the question a second time.

Comment: If you want to know why MS chose to do what they did then you need to ask *them*, not other people, and that is Primarily Opinion Based here.  We can't tell you why MS chose to do what they did or didn't do.

Comment: go to visual studio -> send feedback (on title bar) -> report problem. good luck

Comment: I think this is a valid question - he is asking for people to explain to him if is reasoning is correct and if anyone can provide examples of when this would occur

Comment: @Servy I suspect my answer is correct, that isn't the issue. I would like to know if this is a bug (benign as it is) or not. Yes, I know only MS can answer this with absolute certainty, but that reasoning can apply to hundreds of questions about suspected bugs in the compiler. But whatever, close the question if you consider it the best course of action.

Comment: @Alex Which is *exactly the same as the other question*.

Comment: @InBetween You are correct that all questions asking what MS's intentions are aren't appropriate on SO, and not just this one.  If you're confident that your previous answer is correct, then why are you asking the exact same question again?  Apparently *you already know the answer*, and you know it's correct.

Comment: What happened if `i` was a reference type and in fact `null` ?

Comment: @Servy whether he removes his old answer or not - the current question is valid. If you are suggesting he should remove his old answer before being able to ask this new question you should say that rather than state a valid question is not valid. If you are suggesting he should remove his old answer before he can post this question, I would dispute that, and say if he receives an answer from this question that corrects his previous answer, he should update that answer at that point.

Comment: @Alex Whether he removed his old answer or not, the current question is not valid.  It's literally just asking *exactly* the same thing as the other question; it's an exact duplicate.  Deleting their old answer doesn't make this question any more valid, it's just a good idea since he said that he feels that the answer is wrong.  If he wants to get more attention for the other question, because he has now realized that he no longer knows the answer to it, the correct course of action is to bounty it, not to post the question a second time.

Comment: @Alex Posting a question a second time, just so you can edit any answer  you get into an answer that you posted in the original post of that exact same question, isn't appropriate.

Comment: Are u using Resharper Intellisense or Visual Studio Intellisense?

Comment: @Fildor The pattern match will be succesful and `is` returns `true` if  `var` is used.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is by design, referencing the roslyn source code, starting here: [Binder_Operators, Line 2848](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/1f5f7180a53cd4f6e75a1f5aa85a4c2b7e937b60/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Binder/Binder_Operators.cs#L2848)

> Because the heuristic presented here is used to change codegen, it must be conservative. It is acceptable for us to fail to report a warning in cases where humans could logically deduce that the operator will always return [true]. It is not acceptable to inaccurately warn that the operator will always return [true] if there are cases where it might [fail].