# Different behavior in pattern matching when using var or explicit type

Tags: c#

Consider the following, at first glance absurd, pattern match:

```
string s = null;
if (s is string ss) //false
if (s is string) //false
```

Both `is` will return `false`. However if we use `var` the behavior changes completely:

```
string s = null;
if (s is var ss) //true!?!
```

If you hover over `var` in *VS2017*, the type is `string` but the behavior of `is` is completely different. The compiler is doing something radically different even though the inferred type is the same. How can this be? Is this a bug? Is the `null` type somehow bubbling out?

Comment: isn't 'var ss' defining new, null variable?
Here: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/02/01/pattern-matching.aspx
You can see that it's create temp variable of needed type, then you can check if condition is true.

Comment: @sTrenat Ok, and why `string ss` isn't?

Comment: I think operator 'is' is doing .GetType() and then checking if type is good, for null, there is no type assigned so it can't check it. 
For new 'var' operator, it assign whatever he get

Comment: With new operator, you can write if(s is var ss when (ss!= null)), but it was done for switch operator :p

Comment: @sTrenat huh? The issue is not with `s is string` and however you think it behaves. The issue is the observed difference between both pattern matches: `s is string ss` and `s is var ss` when the *inferred* type of `var` is the *same* (`string`).

Comment: just 's is var' is always true. After temporary assign, you can check if ss is valid in condition, without going into instruction block, it was made for complex switch statment.

Comment: let me quote:
" var patterns, uses the var keyword, and simply copies the source test variable or expression into a new, named variable: ... "

Comment: @sTrenat ok, that explains the behavior but if thats the rule, I'm sorry to say, its slightly bewildering and unexpected, something c# supposedly strives to avoid.

Comment: yes, it's just side effect of "var - when" statements from new switch, which, in my opinion is pretty nice now (switch, not this effect). No more complex if-else structures :d

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C# language reference confirms the behaviour is intended.

> A pattern match with the var pattern always succeeds. Its syntax is

```
expr is var varname
```

> Where the value of expr is always assigned to a local variable named
>   varname. varname is a **static variable of the same type as expr**.
>
> Note that **if expr is null**, the is expression still **is true and assigns null to varname.**

[Source: MSDN - C# Language Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#var)

---

## The `var` pattern

The var pattern just copies the source variable into a new named variable which you can then build a case block expression with like below

```
string s = null;
var collection = new string[] { "abb", "abd", "abc", null};

switch (s)
{
    case "xyz":
        Console.WriteLine("Is xyz");
        break;

    case var ss when (collection).Contains(s):
        Console.WriteLine("Is in list");
        break;

    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Failed!");
        break;

}
```

Output:

```
> Is in list
```

Comment: It's copied from VB. For example you can use now:
switch (age)
{
  case 50:
    ageBlock = "the big five-oh";
    break;
  case var testAge when (new List<int>()
      { 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89 }).Contains(testAge):
    ageBlock = "octogenarian";
    break;
  case var testAge when ((testAge >= 90) & (testAge <= 99)):
    ageBlock = "nonagenarian";
    break;
  case var testAge when (testAge >= 100):
    ageBlock = "centenarian";
    break;
  default:
    ageBlock = "just old";
    break;
}

Or, for if statemant
if (s is var ss, when ss!=null)

Comment: but i don't now if there is any useful case in if( )

Comment: That's right, there wouldn't really be any use of it in an `if` statement.

Comment: @sTrenat well exactly, I understand the `switch` usage but in that case its not a boolean expression with `is`. Its not the `if` clause, its the `is` altogether that I find nonsensical and with an unexpected behavior.

Comment: @InBetween There's an example set out in MSDN to demonstrate the behaviour only, I don't think the var pattern was ever intended to be used with `if` statements at all, but more so with `case` statements. It looks more like it's there to point out that there is (as you suspected) a difference between `is <explicit type>` vs `is <var>`

Comment: can't understand what happens when string is not presented in a collection, i thought second case would be evaluated to null (case null), hence result would be the same, but it seems it's not the case.