# What's the benefit of var patterns in C#7?

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, c#-7.0

I don't understand the use case of `var` patterns in C#7. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#var):

> A pattern match with the `var` pattern always succeeds. Its syntax is

```
expr is var varname
```

> where the value of expr is always assigned to a local variable named
>   `varname`. `varname` is a static variable of the same type as `expr`.

The example on MSDN is pretty useless in my opinion, especially because the `if` is redundant:

```
object[] items = { new Book("The Tempest"), new Person("John") };
foreach (var item in items) {
  if (item is var obj)
    Console.WriteLine($"Type: {obj.GetType().Name}, Value: {obj}"); 
}
```

Here i don't see any benefits, you could have the same if you access the loop variable `item` directly which is also of type `Object`. The `if` is confusing as well because it's never `false`.

I could use `var otherItem = item` or use `item` diectly. 
Can someone explain the use case better?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844586/usage-of-var-pattern-in-c-sharp-7

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904000/different-behavior-in-pattern-matching-when-using-var-or-explicit-type

Comment: IMO this must be seen as an extension of the _is type_ pattern, if `type` is `var`

Comment: @king_nak I agree, but please, please, please say if `var` is `type`, unless you say my blue is car!

Comment: It can be used to introduce a temporary variable: `if (s.FirstOrDefault(o => o != null) is var v && int.TryParse(v, out var n))`

Comment: @Dennis_E This is an excellent example why I'm going to avoid that pattern. It looks like it prevents a null reference exception in the `TryParse` method but it doesn't since the pattern always succeeds. Replacing `var` with the actual type, e.g. `string` would change this behaviour, which is really counterintuitive, if not to say bad.

Comment: @Dirk It's just an example I found. I'm sure there are better ones. But `TryParse` won't cause a null reference exception. It will simply return false.

Comment: @Dennis_E I always thought it would throw an ArgumentNullException if the string was null, but you're right. This doesn't invalidate my criticism of the pattern though.

Comment: You marked the word "static" as code, but it doesn't have special formatting on MSDN. I have no idea what it's supposed to mean here, neither as code nor otherwise.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The *var pattern* was very frequently discussed in the [C# language repository](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang) given that it’s not perfectly clear what its use case is and given the fact that `is var x` does not perform a null check while `is T x` does, making it appear rather useless.

However, it is actually not meant to be used as `obj is var x`. It is meant to be used when the left hand side is *not* a variable on its own.

Here are some examples from [the specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/b650b02f3d62bd287f86bced14c4530b54a59791/proposals/patterns.md). They all use features that are not in C# *yet* but this just shows that the introduction of the var pattern was primarly made in preparation for those things, so they won’t have to touch it again later.

The following example declares a function `Deriv` to construct [the derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) of a function using structural pattern matching on an expression tree:

```
Expr Deriv(Expr e)
{
    switch (e) {
        // …
        case Const(_): return Const(0);
        case Add(var Left, var Right):
            return Add(Deriv(Left), Deriv(Right));
        // …
}
```

Here, the `var` pattern can be used inside the structures to “pull out” elements from the structure. Similarly, the following example simplifies an expression:

```
Expr Simplify(Expr e)
{
    switch (e) {
        case Mult(Const(0), _): return Const(0);
        // …
        case Add(Const(0), var x): return Simplify(x);
    }
}
```

As [gafter writes here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/981#issuecomment-335952271), the idea is also to have property pattern matching, allowing the following:

```
if (o is Point {X is 3, Y is var y})
{ … }
```

Comment: Those are C# 8 records and expressions that can't be used yet. Which is rather annoying

Comment: Yeah, we’ll be getting there though :)

Answer (score 14):

Without checking the design notes on Github I'd guess this was added more for consistency with `switch` and as a stepping stone for more advanced pattern matching cases,

From the original [What’s New in C# 7.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) post :

> Var patterns of the form var x (where x is an identifier), which always match, and simply put the value of the input into a fresh variable x with the same type as the input.

And the recent [dissection post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/10/16/dissecting-the-pattern-matching-in-c-7/) by Sergey Teplyakov :

> if you know what exactly is going on you may find this pattern useful. It can be used for introducing a temporary variable inside the expression:
>   This pattern essentially creates a temporary variable using the actual type of the object.

```
public void VarPattern(IEnumerable<string> s)
{
    if (s.FirstOrDefault(o => o != null) is var v
        && int.TryParse(v, out var n))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
}
```

The warning righ before that snippet is also significant:

> It is not clear why the behavior is different in the Release mode only. But I think all the issues falls into the same bucket: the initial implementation of the feature is suboptimal. But based on this comment by Neal Gafter, this is going to change: "The pattern-matching lowering code is being rewritten from scratch (to support recursive patterns, too). I expect most of the improvements you seek here will come for "free" in the new code. But it will be some time before that rewrite is ready for prime time.".

According to [Christian Nagel](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2017/02/15/patternmatching/) :

> The advantage is that the variable declared with the var keyword is of the real type of the object,

Comment: Thanks. But i don't understand the last sentence(Christian Nagel). If i would use `item` which is `Object`, then `item.GetType().Name` would return the same(`Book` instead of `Object`). So i still don't understand the advantage. I still can't use `Book` members without casting it to that type.

Comment: In `x is var v`, the type of `v` is always the *static type* as `x`. So when it is `object x = new Book()`, then `v` would also be an `object`, not a `Book`. The example in that linked post is just bad because `x.GetType()` will always return the actual object type and has nothing to do with the static type of the variable.

Comment: The example seems broken, `s.FirstOrDefault(o => o != null) is var v` will always be true, and `v` can end up being null. `s.FirstOrDefault(o => o != null) is var v` is **not** the same as `s.FirstOrDefault(o => o != null) is string v`, which is **very** unfortunate :/

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I can think of offhand is if you find that you've written two identical blocks of code (in say a single `switch`), one for `expr is object a` and the other for `expr is null`.

You can combine the blocks by switching to `expr is var a`.

It may also be useful in code generation scenarios where, for whatever reason, you've already written yourself into a corner and always expect to generate a pattern match but now want to issue a "match all" pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases it is true, the var pattern benefit is not clear, and can even be a bad idea. However as a way of capturing anonymous types in temp variable it works great.
Hopefully this example can illustrate this:
Note below, adding a null case avoids var to ever be null, and no null check is required.

```
        var sample = new(int id, string name, int age)[] { 
                                                          (1, "jonas", 50),                                                                                                                            
                                                          (2, "frank", 48) };

        var f48 = from s in sample 
                  where s.age == 48 
                  select new { Name = s.name, Age = s.age };

        switch(f48.FirstOrDefault())
        {
            case var choosen when choosen.Name == "frank":
                WriteLine(choosen.Age);
                break;
            case null:
                WriteLine("not found");
                break;
        }
```