# Why does is type / is var yield different results for null?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Theoretical question: If you use the construct

```
if (someVar is object o) {
```

and you put in `null` for `someVar`, the result will be false. On the other hand, if you use

```
if (someVar is var o) {
```

the result will be true. Why is that so?

Complete code for testing:

```
object obj = null;
if (obj is object o) {
    "object".Dump();
    o.Dump();
}

if (obj is var o2)
{
    "var".Dump();
    o2.Dump();
}
```

Result in LinqPad:

```
var
null
```

Comment: There's a good explanation of the var pattern here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48946329/whats-the-benefit-of-var-patterns-in-c7

Comment: @Dirk Sounds like a good enough duplicate. The *why* is an opinionated question that should be asked at the C# GitHub repository

Comment: The second duplicate even adds further information: "However, there are two cases where var is needed: for anonymous types or if you want to allow nulls. The latter is because null doesn't match any type."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: because `is object` is specified as containing an implicit null-check, but `is var` is specified as not.

The best doc I can find [is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#var-declarations-in-case-expressions) (although that relates specifically to switch statements, and not if statements):

> The introduction of var as one of the match expressions introduces new rules to the pattern match.
>
> The first rule is that the var declaration follows the normal type inference rules: The type is inferred to be the static type of the switch expression. From that rule, the type always matches.
>
> The second rule is that a var declaration doesn't have the null check that other type pattern expressions include. That means the variable may be null, and a null check is necessary in that case.

I can't say I understand the reason behind this (IMO) slightly odd decision...

As pointed out by @Camilo in the comments, [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/10/16/dissecting-the-pattern-matching-in-c-7/) contains some more details. [This question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48946329/whats-the-benefit-of-var-patterns-in-c7) also goes into a lot of detail.

Comment: Ok, so the basic answer is "by definition" :-) Thanks for the documentation link.

Comment: I could add an answer, but I'll just give you more info instead. Look [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/10/16/dissecting-the-pattern-matching-in-c-7/) under "The var pattern"