# Using 'var' with 'is' causes Resharper to say code is heuristically unreachable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, resharper, var

I have this bit of code in a controller

```
if (ValidateId(id) is BadRequestObjectResult invalid)
    return invalid;
```

where `ValidateId` returns a `BadRequestObjectResult` (a reference type).

If I change the code to

```
if (ValidateId(id) is var invalid)
    return invalid;
```

Resharper will complain that all the code after these lines is heuristically unreachable.

I understand that a heuristic is not absolute, but I'm wondering: why Resharper was triggered on this code change?

Comment: I don't know why Resharper calls it "heuristically unreachable". The "var pattern" always evaluates to `true` and therefore the code after the `if` block is simply unreachable. On the other hand, the whole "var pattern" has left people confused, not least because of a rather [bewildering, pointless documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#var). (here is an [inofficial, yet much better explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50660530/2819245) of the usefulness of the "var pattern"). (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Perhaps with letting Resharper say "heuristically unreachable", the Resharper developers expressed their own confusion about `is var`. Who knows... (just in case it is not clear. I do NOT really know why Resharper uses the wording "heuristically unreachable")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R# is absolutely right because you use [var pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#-var-pattern-) that always returns *true* therefore this code is unreachable.

> The var pattern is a catch-all for any type or value. The value of
>   expr is always assigned to a local variable the same type as the
>   compile time type of expr. The result of the is expression is always
>   true. Its syntax is:

```
expr is var varname
```